# Break down $x^4 + 5x^2 +5$

Tags: factoring

How do I break down the function in the title even further? I think that I need to use a square root somewhere, but I'm not certain.

Comment: Let $t=x^2$. Then factorize the quadratic equation using the fact that $ax^2+bx+c=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$.

Comment: substitute $x^2=y$ ; $y^2+5y+5=y^2+5y+4+1=y^2+4y+y+4+1=y(y+4)+1(y+4)+1=[(y+4)(y+1)]+1=[(x^2+4)(x^2+1)]+1$

Answer (score 0):

you can make a change of variable $x^2 = u$ to turn $x^4 + 5x^2 + 5 = 0$ into the quadratic equation $$u^2 + 5u + 5 = 0. $$ this has the solution $$u = \frac{-5 \pm \sqrt{25 - 4 \times 5}}{2} = \frac{-5 \pm \sqrt 5}{2}$$ here we see that both roots are negative. therefore $x^2 = u$ has no real solutions consequently $$x^4 + 5x^2 +5 = 0 $$ has no real solution for $x.$

p.s. if you wanted to factor the expression, then we can use $$u^2 + 5u + 5 = \frac 14(2u + 5 + \sqrt 5)(2u + 5 - \sqrt5) \to\\ x^4 + 5x^2 + 5 =  \frac 14(2x^2 + 5 + \sqrt 5)(2x^2 + 5 - \sqrt5)  $$